# Ruby how to call method from prepended module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model:

```
class MyModel
  prepend MyModelOverride

  def find_something
    #returns something
  end
end

module MyModelOverride
  included do
    def method1
      find_something
    end
  end
end

MyModel.new.method1
```

This last call returns the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `method1' for #<MyModel:0x007f089c673b48>
```

How do I properly format the code in MyModelOverride such that I can call methods in it from an instance of MyModel **and** I can call other methods of MyModel from within it?

Comment: What Ruby version do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To include a method via a mixin/module, all you need is this:

```
module MyModelOverride
  def method1
    find_something
  end
end
```

This will make `method1` an instance method of any class you include it into.

The `included` block you were using in your example comes from [ActiveSupport::Concern](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html). If you want to use the ActiveSupport::Concern for more advanced inclusion concepts, just include it into your module:

```
module MyModelOverride
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    # macros to run when module is included, like `scope` or `has_many` etc.
  end

  def method1
    find_something
  end
end
```

Comment: I didn't see the *ROR* tag, and keep thinking, how you used *block* with `included`... :-)

Comment: @onetwopunch if you're satisfied with an answer please accept it so others know the problem is solved.

Comment: @pdobb Sorry mate, wrote the comment before it allowed me to accept, then went to lunch and forgot :P

Comment: You mean `extend` and not `include` for `ActiveSupport::Concern`

Answer (score 1):

I'd do using [`prepended`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Module.html#method-i-prepended) hook :-

```
module MyModelOverride
  def self.prepended(klass)
    klass.class_eval do
      def method1
        find_something
      end
    end
  end
end


class MyModel
  prepend MyModelOverride

  def find_something
    12
  end
end

MyModel.new.method1 # => 12
```